# What does changing the coefficients of polynomials graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

### Quadratic Function

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

It's obvious that when we change absolute term the vertex of the parabola graphs a vertical line with equation $x=-b/2a$

---

When we change $b$, the vertex traces a parabola with equation $y=-ax^2+c$ as shown here:

> Define $b$ as the parameter $t$ so the parametric equation traces the vertex is $$\left({-t\over2a},f\left({-t\over2a}\right)\right)$$
>   $$\left({-t\over2a},{-t^2+4ac\over4a}\right)$$
>   Now, eliminate the parameter:
>   $$x={-t\over2a}\iff t=-2ax\\y={-t^2+4ac\over4a}={-4a^2x^2+4ac\over 4a}=-ax^2+c\space\square$$

By the same method, when we change $a$ it traces: $$y={b\over 2}x+c$$

---

My question is "Does other polynomials have this pattern? Does this tracing have 
a name? Is there a generalization?"

NB. for cubic we can trace the inflection point. Or the mid-point between the two extrema.

Comment: Your statement "It's obvious that when we change absolute term the vertex of the parabola graphs a vertical line with equation $x=−b/2a$" is not at all obvious. The standard solution for a quadratic never divides $x=−b/2a$. It is unclear what you are asking. Does "change" mean set the coefficient to $0$?

Comment: @WeatherVane I think he refers to $c$ as the absolute term, and so a vertical shift in the parabola is indeed along the line $x=-b/2a$, which refers to the vertex of the parabola.